# Store images in the file system for a live website

Tags: php, mysql

Background info about my website: I'm developing a website with the MAMP stack where people can find vegan products in their area, and they can also upload products that they find, so other people can know where they are found. The products obviously will be stored in a database (mysql), and have an associated image. The website has never gone live yet.

A simple tutorial explains how to store images in the filesystem half way down the page [here](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/upload%20image%20to%20database%20and%20server%20using%20HTML,PHP%20and%20MySQL.php).

**It stores the images in "/xampp/htdocs/images/".**

I can do that, it's pretty basic, but my question is about what happens when the site goes live.

Would saving the images to that folder (but mamp instead of xampp for me), work when the site goes live? I'm guessing no, because the web hosting provider will not have a folder called MAMP at the project folder level. Where do I store it to make it work when the site is live? Do I have to first ask the web hosting provider, then write my code based on that (would be a bit coupled with the hosting provider, all be it, for a small portion of code - and I am also guessing that would be unnecessary).

Comment: Why are you not storing your images in your project folder?

Answer (score 0):

please try to store your images in your project folder ,this will work  even when you will go live .there you can set permission on image folder who  can access that images folder. i have cpanel and i did that it is working.